# Can a struct of doubles be typecast to an array of doubles in C?

Tags: c, struct, casting

Is this legal in C?

```
struct Doubles
{
  double a,b,c;
};

void foo(struct Doubles* bar)
{
  double* baz = (double*)bar;
  baz[0]++;
  baz[1]++;
  baz[2]++;
}
```

I know that it "works" on MSVC 2010, but I don't know if it's legal, or if different layouts could cause UB.

Comment: While it should work OK with most compilers, the question I have for you is how is better than using `bar->a`, `bar->b`, and `bar->c`?

Comment: @RSahu I was hoping to iterate over the members of the struct in a loop, since I need to do the exact thing on each of the members. I can wrap the operation in a function, and then call the function with a pointer to the three members (which is probably what I'll do, given that the answer seems to be "no, this is not totally safe"), but it's a little less convenient.

Comment: @anjruu Use an array if you want to iterate.

Comment: @self I am using an existing library. The struct in question represents a point, and the original authors of the code chose to represent a point as a struct with members for the x, y, and z positions.

Comment: @anjruu You will have to call the members, unless you want to have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This leads to undefined behaviour. The layout of the struct is not totally prescribed by the standard.  For instance, there may be padding.

Comment: I think you explained well.

Comment: Maybe add that for efficiency and to easily fulfill the "compatible type" and "union" requirements, after each member in just about every implementation only the minimal neccessary amount of padding is added to satisfy alignment constraints. Thus, the initial part of a struct starting with two `T` would be compatible to an array of two `T` in practice.

Comment: The layout is implementation-defined (and in practice always defined the way you want it to be); that is not the issue that causes undefined behavior. Rather, undefined behavior here is caused by aliasing. An object of type `struct Doubles` cannot alias an object of type `double[3]`, and the compiler is allowed to assume they don't alias, meaning reads and writes may be reordered freely in ways that break your code.

Comment: @R.. Strict aliasing rules apply to the fundamental type, which is `double` in both cases. So, no, aliasing does not render this code UB.

Comment: Maybe. There're also the array bounds rules. `double* baz = (double*)bar; baz[0]++;` is legal, `baz+1` is legal as a pointer one past the end of the "length-1 array" `bar.a`, `baz[1]++` is UB (dereferencing thast pointer), and `baz[2]` simply invokes illegal pointer arithmetic (UB) before the dereference takes place. So there are lots of issues here.

Comment: @R.. cmaster I agree there is no aliasing problem, but restrictions, R. stated, apply. I wouldn't even allow the baz+1 since there is no array.

Comment: @this: The C standard is explicit that `&x+1` is valid pointer arithmetic for any `x` where `&x` is valid.

Comment: @R.. Do you have the reference, I can only find that stated for an array. 6.5.6,8 Nevermind, 6.5.6,7 clears that up.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler is allowed to pad/pack the structure however it likes, so strictly speaking, your code isn't 100% safe.  It'll work on most implementations, though.

Comment: Afaik, the memory layout of a `struct` is described quite strictly, i. e. it is guaranteed to use the requested order. And the padding within a structure will be the same as in an array.

Comment: There are limitations: Only after members, any structs with the same initial sequence must have them at the same offsets.

Comment: @cmaster Padding in struct same as an array? Really? Where is that specified in the standard?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What do you need padding for? You need it, to align the next member to a boundary that allows fast access by the CPU. Nothing more or less. And the CPU does not care whether it is loading from a `struct` or an array, heck, it doesn't even know. Consequently, any sane compiler must use the same padding in both cases.

Comment: @cmaster we are talking about the standard rather than any specific implementation

Comment: @cmaster - yes, the fields have to be in order (among other restrictions).  What's that got to do with padding/packing?

Comment: @CarlNorum If I know the alignment of the values, and I know the order of the values, I can **calculate** the precise offset of each struct member. Yes, the standard does not require the padding in struct and array contexts to be the same, but it even defines the `_Alignof` operator, which yields **the** alignment of a type. It would be extremely curious if a compiler used a larger alignment than that in *any* context. The trick will work in any sane environment, even without the explicit blessing of the standard.